# CKeditor 5 remove attributes

Tags: ckeditor

const htmlSupport = [{

```
    name: /^(h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|sub|u|section|blockquote|em|hr|strong|div|p|img|table|tr|td|thead|tbody|ul|ol|li|a|figure)$/,

    attributes: {
        border: true,
        width: true,
        href: true,
        align: true,
        colspan: true,
        rowspan: true,
        src: true
    },

    styles: {
        width: true,
        border: true,
        'font-size': true,
        'font-weight': true,
        'border-width': true
    }

}];

ClassicEditor.create(ck, {
    htmlSupport: { allow: htmlSupport }
})
```

When i load html

Some text

After load Ckeditor don`t cut  background-color, but this attribute is not in allow object

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).